# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, string

**Error trace:**

```
C:\Users\Abhi.Abhi-PC\Desktop\PYE>ex25ex.py Traceback (most recent
call last):   File "C:\Users\Abhi.Abhi-PC\Desktop\PYE\ex25ex.py", line
41, in <module>     print_last_word(sentence)   File
"C:\Users\Abhi.Abhi-PC\Desktop\PYE\ex25ex.py", line 17, in
print_last_word     word = words.pop(1) AttributeError: 'str' object
has no attribute 'pop'
```

Here is the code

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split()
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

sentence="island has lush vegetation, area. However, summers are cooler than those  abundant."

break_words(sentence)
sort_words(sentence)
print_last_word(sentence)
print_last_word(sentence)
print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
print_first_and_last(sentence)
```

I am unable to figure the issue with the problem. I am working from the book "How to learn Python hard way".

Comment: as the error says, you are trying to call `pop()` on the `str` but this function is not available with stings

Comment: sentence is a string but in `print_last_word` you might expect it to be list there for the function to work ... also for last word you might want to make `words.pop(-1)` instead of 1.

Comment: what should I do then to use pop?

Comment: make use of `break_words` that you have written to first convert it to list then use `pop()`

Comment: thanks guys problem has been solved

Comment: @AbhishekKaushik Best way is to typecast your string to list and then call `pop`. This should work `list(words).pop(value)`

Comment: Also, there are better books than the learn python the hard way; for example the [Invent with Python series](https://inventwithpython.com/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here, is remove a word from a string. When you try to `sentence.pop()`, you are trying to remove an element from an Immutable Sequence Type. Which means that you are trying to remove an element from a string, which does not make too much sense. What you should instead do, is break the string into words by `words.split(' ')` and then removing whichever element you want to remove from it. So a solution to replace line 17 is:

`word = words.split(' ').pop(len(words.split(' '))-1)`

That will remove the last word from the sentence and assign it to `word`.

Note: This is obviously not the most efficient solution. I broke it down to make it readable.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you ignore the return values of your functions, especially `break_words`, and always operate over the original input. This would fix the problem:

```
words = break_words(sentence)
sort_words(words)
print_first_word(words)
print_last_word(words)
print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
print_first_and_last(sentence)
```

There is another small issue that you should use `words.pop(-1)` to access the last item in the words list.

How could you have identified the problem from the error message. The exception is an AttributeError that states that `'str' object has no attribute 'pop'`. So apparently, in the line `words.pop(0)`, words is a string, not a list of strings, as the variable name suggests. It then only needs a quick glance to see why this variable is a string: when you call the function with `print_last_word(sentence)` you pass it the original data (of type `str`) rather than the preprocessed data that you might have intended to pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split()
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print(word)

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print(word)

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

sentence="island has lush vegetation, area. However, summers are cooler than those  abundant."

wordList=break_words(sentence)
print('')
print('wordList:',wordList)
print('')
print('Sorted :',sort_words(wordList))
print('')
print_first_word(wordList)
print('')
print_last_word(wordList)
print('')
print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
print('')
print_first_and_last(sentence)
```

**RESULT**

```
wordList: ['island', 'has', 'lush', 'vegetation,', 'area.', 'However,', 'summers', 'are', 'cooler', 'than', 'those', 'abundant.']

Sorted : ['However,', 'abundant.', 'are', 'area.', 'cooler', 'has', 'island', 'lush', 'summers', 'than', 'those', 'vegetation,']

island

abundant.

However,
vegetation,

island
abundant.
```

Comment: thanks!! I got your point. But the problem has not been solved. Now also, it showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

See `pop()` is not a string function so going forward you can create a function, pass n as the index of the character you need to pop out of the string as str.
write below code into the popout:

```
def popout(str,n):
  front = str[:n]   # up to but not including n
  back = str[n+1:]  # n+1 through end of string
  return front + back
```

> This might answer your question as per my understanding. if not, please
>   correct me in the comment section.